# AngularJS ngInclude dynamically changing its location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a few partial templates where the location is changed based on user actions via ng-click:

```
<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>

<button ng-click="contentUrl = '../partials/testScriptForm.html'">Add Test Script</button>
```

This works great unless I the button above is inside of the partial itself, so if testScriptForm.html has a button:

```
<button ng-click="contentUrl = '../partials/testScriptCase.html'">Add Test Case</button>
```

Then nothing happens.

This seems due to ng-include getting a new (inherited but not shared?) scope.

What I can't figure is how to get the included template (partial) to change its own location.

I did try a function to change the $scope.$parent.contentUrl, it does seem to change but not "propagate" the changes.

In coffeescript:

```
  $scope.changeParentLocation = (location) ->
      $scope.$parent.contentUrl = location
```

Also tried to $scope.$apply() and $scope.$parent.$apply() in there and get the error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Maybe I'm just mis-using includes...

Comment: Try using an object `"content.Url='someFile.html'"` instead of just `"contentUrl='someFile.html'"`

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out why ng-click couldn't change the included template and would have never guessed it was due to a new scope..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the isolated scope with "dotted model" reference:

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" charset="utf-8" id="/partials/testScriptForm.html">
      <h1>This is testScriptForm.html</h1>
      <button ng-click="tpl.contentUrl = '/partials/testScriptCase.html'">Change to Test Case</button>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" charset="utf-8" id="/partials/testScriptCase.html">
      <h1>This is testScriptCase.html</h1>
      <button ng-click="tpl.contentUrl = '/partials/testScriptForm.html'">Change to Test Form</button>
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

      <fieldset>
        <div ng-include="tpl.contentUrl"></div>
      </fieldset>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.tpl = {};
  $scope.tpl.contentUrl = '/partials/testScriptForm.html';
}
```

Comment: I think this needs a short explanation. This has actually to do with how JavaScript will copy things. Without the dot, we are referencing a scalar variable. If JavaScript makes a copy of that, it is just that, a copy. Any changes made to the copy will not reflect on the original.

On the other hand: If there is a dot, then the "copy" is not of a scalar variable but an object (tpl in the answer). And a object is "copied" by reference, thus the copied tpl will still point to the original object, thus tpl.whatever will change tpl.whatever on the "original" as well.

Comment: Thanks to all responders that totally solved it and the explanation makes perfect sense.  In fact I had tried some simple experiments (thinking this was because I was using a primitive type and copying not referencing was the issue) by using ng-click="shared = { prop: 1 }"  etc on the buttons but it wasn't working...but the simple dot notation is good...personally I blame it being Friday afternoon at the time of posting ;)